# Code a button to open form, based on what is selected in list box (list box selected index is from a SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, listbox

I am building an application that is full of items for shopping and such, and the user (after having logged in and selected "Browse Categories") then can see a list box and button (alongside a button to go back). The list box has the category names, and for each category, there's a form that holds the data for items under that category. The list box has a data binding to a SQL Server, of which the selected index is the table "tblNamesOfCats". The button below it says "Select Category". The user is supposed to select a category, and then click the button to view the form for that category. However, I tried the following code -

```
Private Sub btnSelectCat_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSelectCat.Click

    If lbxCatList.SelectedItem = ("Action Figures") Then
        frmCatsActionFigures.Show()
    End If

End Sub
```

Note-btnSelectCat is the button, lbxCatList is the listbox, and frmCatsActionFigures is the form for the Action Figures category.

However, when I try to debug this, I end up getting this error -

```
Overload resolution failed because no Public '=' can be called with these arguments:

'Public Shared Operator =(a As String, b As String) As Boolean':

    Argument matching parameter 'a' cannot convert from 'DataRowView' to 'String'.
```

What code should I use? How would I fix this?

UPDATE(1)-
The Listbox, as said earlier, is populated by a SQL Server table, which the table just has one column, called "Category Names", and the rows are just full of the names of each category.
Here are some screenshots of the errors(apparently you must follow the link, as I don't have  a high enough reputation to post images)-

https://sites.google.com/a/devincave.com/temporaryimagesite/

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub btnSelectCat_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSelectCat.Click

    If lbxCatList.SelectedItem.ToString() = "Action Figures" Then
        frmCatsActionFigures.Show()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: When I try this, nothing happens

Comment: what if you debug lbxCatList.SelectedItem.ToString() to see what is the actual value when clicking the button.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean. Could you explain more? And I did try debugging to where when I click the button, a messagebox appears showing the list box's selected item with the following code-
    MessageBox.Show(lbxCatList.SelectedItem.ToString)
But, when I debug, this is what is shown in the message box-
"System.Data.DataRowView"

Comment: try lbxCatList.Items(lbxCatList.SelectedIndex).ToString

Comment: I tried that code, nothing happened (again). So, again, I used a message box to see what would show. Again, it was System.Data.DataRowView

Comment: How are you populating the listbox ?

Comment: The listbox's "List Box Tasks" field is set to use data bound items, and the data source is "TblNamesOfCatsBindingSource" and the display member is "Category". See the images in the link in the edited question

Comment: I wanted the listbox so it would be much 'simpler' (of which apparently not, lol), however I could always just make a button for each category. Would that work best?

Answer (score 0):

When you bind a database table to a listbox, the rows from the datarowview (datasource) are stored in the listbox as opposed to data in columns in those rows.  So it is not text. but DRV objects.  In the error message:

```
Argument matching parameter 'a' cannot convert from 'DataRowView' to 'String'
```

"Action Figures" is the 'String' part, the SelectedItem is a DRV object row, so you must treat it that way.

```
  ' works for ONE col views or when the column you want is #0 
  ' else use the right index
   If lbxCatList.SelectedItem.Item(0).ToString = "Action Figures" Then
```

or

```
   If lbxCatList.SelectedItem.Item("Category").ToString = "Action Figures" Then
```

or cast it back to a drv row (above is basically shorthand for this):

```
   Dim drv As DataRowView = lbxCatList.SelectedItem

   If drv.Item("Category").ToString                  ' or use index of 0
```

Using the latter version, you could set a break here and hover your mouse over `drv` to see all the properties and values to puzzle out where what you want is located and how to get it